# Where are my section numbers?

Tags: sectioning

I'm writing my thesis and after compiling I can see the section (sub and subsub) numberings in the contents page but in the actual body no numbers are seen. They should be there and I can't understand why.

How can I get the section numberings in the body?

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}%\textsl{\rightmark}}
%%\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{caption}
%,labelfont=bf,font=small

\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display] % shape
{\bfseries\huge\sc} % format
{{\begin{center}\Huge Chapter\ \thechapter\end{center}}}  % label
{0.5ex} % sep
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \vspace{-0.6ex}
    \centering
} % before-code
[
    \vspace{-1.0ex}%
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
] % after-code

\titleformat
{\section} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Large\sc\raggedright} % format
{\thesection} % label
{1em} % sep
{} % before commands
[\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}] % after commands (optional, remove square braces entirely to set as nothing)

\titleformat
{\subsection} % command
[hang] % shape
{\large\sc\raggedright} % format
{\thesubsection} % label
{1em} % sep
{}

\titleformat
{\subsubsection} % command
[hang] % shape
{\large\sc\raggedright} % format
{\thesubsubsection} % label
{1em} % sep
{}

\titleformat
{\paragraph} % command
[hang] % shape
{\large\sc\raggedright} % format
{\theparagraph} % label
{1em} % sep
{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction} \label{c1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{The first section} 
\subsection{The first subsection}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{bib} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As always on this site, you are much mush more likely to get proper help if you provide a full but minimal example showcasing your problem. The example should be selv contained such that others can use it for testing without having to add anything. Here here is no document class, preamble or sample document.

Comment: I can think of a situation where this can happen: the `memoir` class when `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` are used. But you gave no information so it is just a guess.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't get the output you show in your pictures if I compile a document with a `\section` and your preamble. Please post a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Your code segment isn't a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Try making an MWE and add it here. Btw, it might be due to some use of the `titlesec` package.

Comment: As already mentioned please provide a complete example that displays your problem. We cannot test as long as we only get sniplets

Comment: your new example is longer but generates `! LaTeX Error: File \`intro.tex' not found.` If I ignore that, the only section heading is `\chapter{Introduction}` and that is numbered as chapter 1

Comment: If I take your new example and replace `\input{intro.tex}` by `\section{The first section} \subsection{The first subsection}`, I get a section and a subsection, both numbered.

Comment: Do I need to put something in my intro.tex document then as when I fully compile there are no section numbers.

Comment: @TOM thanls for making a usable example, If I run it I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n29Uc.png) with chapter, section and subsection all numbered. So there does not seem to be any problem to solve? Please replace the image in the question by the output that you get from the posted code, as clearly non one can generate the output you currently show.